# Java Math.random with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to populate my 2d array that is 5 by 5 with a char such as A in random coordinates in the 2d array. When I use my nested for loop i wanted to make the coordinates of the 2d array where my char will be to be random. So lets say I asked for 40 percent of A's, in a 5 by 5 I should get 10 A's but I get 8. When i run it, it doesn't show the percentage of A's i wanted sometimes. it would only print out like 6. Is this because when the row and col in the if statement are randomized, so is the row and col in the for loop? Is this why the char sometimes populates less then asked for because the for loop stops if the number randomizes the length of the 2d array which is 5?

Also when it does print out 10 char, sometimes they go over the 5 by 5. an example would be 2 As in the line and 7 in the second and 1 in the 3rd. Why is that?

```
public static void grid(char[][] arr, int percentofchar)
{

  double charx = 0.0;

  double totalpercentchar = 0;
  totalpercentchar = (double) percentofchar / 100;

  cellx = totalpercentchar * (arr.length * arr.length);

  for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
    {
      if (charx > 0)
      {
        row = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
        col = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
        charx--;
        arr[row][col] = 'A';
        System.out.print(arr[row][col] + "  ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your original code? `cellx` looks like it should be `charx`?

Comment: yeah, I did cellx first to make my char 'X' but then realized it could be any char so changed the name , missed that thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: also had a bunch of classes with somewhat the same code to try different ways so that could of been why i missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code should be something like

```
public static void grid(char[][] array, int percentOfChar)
  {
    int charsToPlace = (int) (percentOfChar * array.length * array.length / 100.0);
    while (charsToPlace > 0)
    {
        int row = (int) (Math.random() * array.length);
        int column = (int) (Math.random() * array.length);
        if (array[row][column] != 'A');
        {
            array[row][column] = 'A';
            charsToPlace--;
            System.out.print(array[row][column] + "  ");
        }          
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

No need to loop through the array and to use nested loop if you are only trying to insert a char in a random position.

Also

> Is this because when the row and col in the if statement are
>   randomized, so is the row and col in the for loop?  Is this why the char sometimes populates 
>   less then asked for because the for loop stops if the number
>   randomizes the length of the 2d array which is 5? Also when it does print out 10 char, 
>   sometimes they go over the 5 by 5. an example would be 2 As in the
>   line and 7 in the second and 1 in the 3rd. Why is that?

More or less. You randomize row and column, but in doing so it could lead to a premature end of the iteration through the array. As a worst case scenario, consider what happens if the first time you enter the `if` statement the random functions assign the 4 values to both `row` and `col`. In general, are you sure that at the end of the `grid` method `charx` will always be equals to 0?

---

**Considerations**

As Matt pointed out in the below comments, this method has no check on the array; so, it assumes that the array is always a square one (i.e. row X column = n X n).
If you want to force the use of a square array, you may want to create a wrapper class, e.g.

```
class IntegerSquareArray
{
    public final int length;
    int[][] array;
    IntegerSquareArray(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.array = new int[length][length];
    }

    public int getValue(int row, int column)
    {
        if (row < length && column < length)
            return array[row][column];
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public void setValue(int row, int column, int value)
    {
        if (row < length && column < length)
            array[row][column] = value;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply change the `grid` code to be

```
public static void grid3(IntegerSquareArray integerSquareArray,
    int percentOfChar)
{
    int charsToPlace = (int) (percentOfChar * integerSquareArray.length
        * integerSquareArray.length / 100.0);
    while (charsToPlace > 0)
    {
        int row = (int) (Math.random() * integerSquareArray.length);
        int column = (int) (Math.random() * integerSquareArray.length);
        if (integerSquareArray.getValue(row, column) != 'A')
        {
            integerSquareArray.setValue(row, column, 'A');
            charsToPlace--;
            System.out.print(integerSquareArray.getValue(row, column) + "  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: +1 agree with this, although if he's looking to insert a specific percentage of A's in the grid he ought to also check whether the target cell already contains an 'A' before decrementing `charx`. I'd also consider renaming `charx` to something sensible like `charsToPlace`... also it appears this code is assuming the grid is square

Comment: @MattCoubrough yeah, some unhappy naming in the code, I've modified my answer.

Comment: Be warned that this starts to become horribly inefficient when percentOfChar is high, because you start getting more attempts to place in cells that already contain 'A's... One way I have got around this in the past in my code is to create a list of all possible cell positions, shuffle that list, then place an object into the first `n` cell positions from the shuffled list... this solution becomes O(N) after the initial list creation and shuffle which is ideal.

Comment: @MattCoubrough great, it should be another useful trick. Also, about the grid square part, I think you're right. Before square, it assumes that the array is rectangular also, that is not always the case. So, what do you think could be a good workaround? Some ideas: 1) iterate through the whole array (sounds too unefficient); 2) provide a column and row length as parameters; 3) let everything as is and warn the user that `array` parameter should be a square array.

Comment: Not wanting to digress too much in comment, but usually its best to represent a grid with a `class` with `Width` and `Height` properties rather than just use a multidimensional array. That way the code makes more sense and effectively becomes self commenting...

Comment: @MattCoubrough yes, something like a wrapper with getters ad setters, isn't it?

Comment: Have added my shuffle approach answer for completeness

Comment: Yeah Matt was right I'm trying to put it in a grid. Tiger thanks for your help, I think I can work with it. I'm trying to make my output look somethings like scattered 10 A's in a 5 by 5 grid and anything else should be a blank space. I think  I can work with what you said. I will try it and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @NickCage Read also Matt answer and the comments below. And don't forget to accept an answer ;)

Comment: Hey guys, I used your advice and made a lot of progress with the rest of my work! I posted a new question on a part which I'm having difficulty with. I would appreciate it if you can check it out and let me know what you think on how I can go about it. Thanks and thanks for the help on this one as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is what I mentioned in the comments under [tigerjack's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858629/3651800) solution. As per the comments, I would use a wrapper for the grid rather than a raw multidimensional array.

My random placement solution is a little bit more complicated, but it will be much more efficient for higher placement percentages (ie. if you're trying to fill greater than 90% of the cells) and will always fill the exactly specified percent of characters.

If desired, you could use tigerjack's method for random placements when `percentOfCellsToSet` is lower, and this method when `percentOfCellsToSet` is higher using an `if` statement in the `setRandomCells()` method.

Here is my complete compileable example using the shuffled list method:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyGrid
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private char[][] grid;

    public MyGrid(int width, int height, char defaultCell)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;        
        grid = new char[height][width];

        // populate grid with defaultCells:
        for(int x=0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                grid[y][x] = defaultCell;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWidth() { return width; }

    public int getHeight() { return height; }

    public char getCell(int x, int y) { return grid[y][x]; }

    public void setCell(int x, int y, char cellValue) { grid[y][x] = cellValue; }

    public void setRandomCells(char cellValue, float percentOfCellsToSet)
    {
        // determine the number of cells to set (rounding to nearest int):
        int numCellsToSet = (int)(Math.round((width * height * percentOfCellsToSet) / 100.0));

        // create a list containing all possible cell positions:
        List<Point> listAllCellLocations = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int x=0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            for(int y=0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                listAllCellLocations.add(new Point(x,y));
            }
        }

        // shuffle it
        Collections.shuffle(listAllCellLocations);

        // now set the cells
        for(int i=0; i < numCellsToSet; ++i)
        {
            Point pt = listAllCellLocations.get(i);
            setCell(pt.x, pt.y, cellValue);
        }
    }

    public void debugPrintGrid()
    {
        for(int y=0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for(int x=0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                System.out.print(getCell(x,y));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyGrid myGrid = new MyGrid(10, 10, '0');
        myGrid.setRandomCells('A', 68);
        myGrid.debugPrintGrid();
    }

}
```

and here is the sample output from the code in the `main()` method:

```
AAAA0A0AAA
0AAAAAAAA0
A00A00AA0A
AAAAA0AAA0
AA0A0AAAA0
0A0AAAA0AA
A0AAA0A0AA
A0A00AAAAA
AAA000A0A0
0AA0AAA0A0
```

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: well, you know, I'm like S. Thomas and I tested a bit with mine and your code and these are the results of 100,000 simulations with min, max and average values (it assumes a 15x15 array).
With percentOfCellToSet = 90% http://pastebin.com/W90WUALR

With percentOfCellToSet = 40% http://pastebin.com/XAgaBru5

Comment: Nice work with profiling: With a 1000 x 1000 grid and a percent of 95% I get marginally better performance with my method on my machine (omitting any console output which might skew results). At 100% coverage on a 1000 x 1000 grid I get more than 3x faster performance with my method. At 90% your method seems to always be quicker. Shows the importance of profiling!

Comment: you're using the first method (without the wrapper class), right? I've tested it using the second one (with the IntegerSquareArray class). Also, I've modified my test cases to take into account your shuffle approach with my IntegerSquareArray. I'll show the result in a few minutes.

Comment: This is the test code I used http://pastebin.com/nAbVvdyZ (it should be improved in some ways, but it works, so... :) ) and these are some outputs http://pastebin.com/1udyV48J
Very interesting

Comment: As summary, assuming x the percentage of cells to be set:
- 0<x<70 the simple method is better (almost 2 times faster on average)
- 70<x<98 there is little difference; at 80% random placement method became a little more faster
- 98<x<100 simple method raise the white flag: from 2 to 7 times slower than random placement method

Answer (score 0):

You assign random values to the cycle variables... Now this is as undeterministic as it could be...

Basically your nested loops will end if by any chance the first `Math.random()` results in `arr.length - 1` and the 2nd results in `arr[arr.length - 1].length -1`.

I seriously doubt this is what you wanted.

To control how many random `A`s to put into the array, just use a loop for that but don't assign random values to the cycle variable:

```
int max = arr.length * arr.length * percentofchar / 100;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // Put `A` at a random location
    int row = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
    int col = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
    arr[row][col] = 'A';
    System.out.print(arr[row][col] + "  ");
}
```

Also note that this still might result in less `A` than the percent would mean because the same random location might be generated multiple times, so the same array element might be set to `A` multiple times.

If you want to generate exact count of `A`s, you have to retry if the random location is already an `A`:

```
int max = arr.length * arr.length * percentofchar / 100;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    // Put `A` at a random location
    int row, col;
    do {
        row = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
        col = (int) (Math.random() * arr.length);
    } while (arr[row][col] == 'A');
    arr[row][col] = 'A';
    System.out.print(arr[row][col] + "  ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code places "A"s randomly, so some "A" may placed on same place.

Let calculate possibility to see 10 "A"s as result.

First "A" is always empty place, so you see 1 "A" at 100%
For placing second "A", there are 1 place occupied by "A" and 24 empty place, so you see 2 "A" after placing second "A" at 96%. (Second A may placed where first "A" placed in possibility 1 out of 25(4%).
For third, possibility is (24/25) * (23/25).
  ... omitted in 4th to 9th .
For 10th, you see 10 "A"s in possibility of (24/25)*(23/25)*(22/25)*(21/25)*(20/25)*(19/25)*(18/25)*(17/25)*(16/25). (The value is about 12.4%)

This calculation says that you code may show 10 "A"s in result about once by eight.

Comment: well, actually it isn't the main reason why the As aren't displayed well. If you check the code again, you can see that the random functions could lead to the premature end of the iteration through the array.

Comment: I think "A"s are placed well randomly. Problem is Nobody can distinguish single "A" and multiple "A"s from the printed "A".

Comment: Not true. What if the first time you enter the if statement the random functions assign the value 4 to both `row` and `col`? In general, are you sure that at the end of the `grid` method `charx` will always be equals to 0?